# $\operatorname{int}_ {\tau_1}(A) \subseteq\operatorname{int}_{\tau_2}(A) $ and $ \overline{A}^{\tau_1} \supseteq\overline{A}^{\tau_2}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2 $ topologies over a set $X$ such that $ \tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 $. Show that for every $ A \subseteq X $, you have to $\operatorname{int}_{\tau_1}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}_{\tau_2}(A)$ and $\overline{A}^{\tau_1} \supseteq \overline{A}^{\tau_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition for the closure inclusion is the following: the finer the topology, the more open sets (and so the more closed sets) you have. Since the closure of a set $A$ is the intersections of all closed sets that contain $A$, then it follows that if I take the intersection over *more* sets (the case of the closure of $A$ in $\tau_2$) I will get a (weakly) smaller set.

Answer (score 1):

- Once you know that $V \in \tau_2$ and $x \in V \subseteq A$, it follows that $x \in \operatorname{int}_{\tau_2}(A)$. It is not true that $V \in \operatorname{int}_{\tau_2}(A)$.
- If $x \in \overline{A}^{\tau_2}$, take a fundamental $\tau_1$-neighborhood system $\mathcal V(x)$ of $x$. Then, as $\mathcal V(x) \subseteq \tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$, $\mathcal V(x)$ is also a fundamental $\tau_2$-neighborhood system of $x$, and since we are assuming that $x \in \overline{A}^{\tau_2}$, it follows that $V \cap A \neq \varnothing$ for all $V \in \mathcal V(x)$. Hence $x \in \overline{A}^{\tau_1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{int}_{\tau_1}(A)$ is a $\tau_2$-open subset of $A$ by the inclusion of topologies. $\operatorname{int}_{\tau_2}(A)$ is the *maximal* $\tau_2$-open subset of $A$. The inclusion follows.

$\overline{A}^{(\tau_1)}$ is a $\tau_1$-closed hence also $\tau_2$-closed superset of $A$. $\overline{A}^{(\tau_2)}$ is the *minimal* $\tau_2$-closed superset of $A$. The inclusion follows.